# How to create a new column in pandas, containing index difference to the previous specific value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cumsum

Having the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.ones(10).reshape(10,1), columns=['A'])
df.ix[2]['A'] = 0
df.ix[6]['A'] = 0

   A
0  1
1  1
2  0
3  1
4  1
5  1
6  0
7  1
8  1
9  1
```

I am trying to add a new column `B` which would contain a number of "1"-occurrences in the column `A` until the first "0"-event before. Expected output should be like this:

```
   A  B
0  1  0
1  1  2
2  0  0
3  1  0
4  1  0
5  1  3
6  0  0
7  1  0
8  1  0
9  1  3
```

Any efficient vectorized way to do this?

Comment: It would help us if you showed what you have tried.

Comment: not much so far. looking for an indication. Could lookup-method work for this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
a = df.A.groupby((df.A != df.A.shift()).cumsum()).cumcount() + 1
print (a)
0    1
1    2
2    1
3    1
4    2
5    3
6    1
7    1
8    2
9    3
dtype: int64

b = ((~df.A.astype(bool)).shift(-1).fillna(df.A.iat[-1].astype(bool)))
print (b)
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
6    False
7    False
8    False
9     True
Name: A, dtype: bool
```

```
df['B'] = ( a * b )
print (df)
     A  B
0  1.0  0
1  1.0  2
2  0.0  0
3  1.0  0
4  1.0  0
5  1.0  3
6  0.0  0
7  1.0  0
8  1.0  0
9  1.0  3
```

Explanation:

```
#difference with shifted A
df['C'] = df.A != df.A.shift()
#cumulative sum
df['D'] = (df.A != df.A.shift()).cumsum()
#cumulative count each group
df['a'] = df.A.groupby((df.A != df.A.shift()).cumsum()).cumcount() + 1

#invert and convert  to boolean
df['F'] = ~df.A.astype(bool)
#shift
df['G'] = (~df.A.astype(bool)).shift(-1)
#fill last nan
df['b'] = (~df.A.astype(bool)).shift(-1).fillna(df.A.iat[-1].astype(bool))

print (df)
     A  B      C  D  a      F      G      b
0  1.0  0   True  1  1  False  False  False
1  1.0  2  False  1  2  False   True   True
2  0.0  0   True  2  1   True  False  False
3  1.0  0   True  3  1  False  False  False
4  1.0  0  False  3  2  False  False  False
5  1.0  3  False  3  3  False   True   True
6  0.0  0   True  4  1   True  False  False
7  1.0  0   True  5  1  False  False  False
8  1.0  0  False  5  2  False  False  False
9  1.0  3  False  5  3  False    NaN   True
```

Last `NaN` is problematic. So I check last value of column `A` by `df.A.iat[-1]` and convert to `boolean`. So if it is `0`, output is `False` and finally `0` or if `1`, output is `True` and then is used last value of `a`.

Comment: Kick-ass! Thank you